# Create a simple private message system in rails with inbox, send, and reply's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, private, message, inbox

There are some gems out there to instantly have a simple messaging system for users which I have looked at but they don't really fit the bill in terms of having a way to easy customize them.

Therefore I would like to ask some suggestions of gems that you consider be good for an instant messaging on a site, or discuss how one could implement this functionality.

I have built a simple system before that consisted of a messages table like this:

- inbox
- outbox
- friend request
- replies

`id|message_id|sender_id|receiver_id|is_reply|is_friendreq|message`

I'm thinking of storing everything in this one table and get all messages of a certain user where the `user_id == receiver_id`. This is very basic. I'm learning Rails and try to learn how to implement this on best Rails practice, so any tips/suggestions/ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: Which gems have you looked at so far?

Comment: The only "up2date" one is this https://github.com/jongilbraith/simple-private-messages.git I think I should just look at that one and build mine based on its concepts, in the end its not that hard think most logic in there seems quite okay.